# How to get only one column from MySQL with ST_Distance_Sphere

Tags: mysql, spatial-query

I have a table with list of cities and GPS coordinates, like:
`id, name, lat, lon` from which I am searching to get a nearest city as a result

```
select
    name, 
    ST_Distance_Sphere(point(lon, lat), point('20.073602', '49.937056') )/1000 as distance 
    from city 
    order by distance asc LIMIT 1;
```

but **how to receive from this query only a 'city' field (one column)** as a result without second column which is distance?

Here is my SQL fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hdshw2KCjNZrXZoKQQgoKR/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your expression directly in `order by` clause

```
select
    name
from city 
order by ST_Distance_Sphere(point(lon, lat), point('20.073602','49.937056') )/1000 asc
limit 1;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hdshw2KCjNZrXZoKQQgoKR/3)

Comment: I know that this must be easy but I didn't know that I can use expression in order. thank yoy for really fast and accurate reply